# Writing a regex for url with the parameter

Tags: python, regex

What will be the regex for `index12.php?cart123=123sadasd`

all strings are supposed to be alphanumeric

(I am trying to write it in python but doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Please choose a title which is useful for other people with the same issue.

Comment: Is it a good question now? @DavidArias

Comment: Now it has sense, you need the regex pattern for the parameters at the url.

Comment: Try it out here: https://regex101.com/ See what works.

Comment: Hey @william3031 yes that is working fine I tried already

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This pattern could help you:

```
(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

For example:

```
import re

url = "index12.php?cart123=123sadasd&user=nickname"
x = re.findall("(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)", url)

if x:
  print(x)
else:
  print("No match")
```

The output will be:

```
[('?', 'cart123', '123sadasd'), ('&', 'user', 'nickname')]
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks.... inspired by your regex I made this `([^=]+)(\.)([^=]+)(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)` that fills my need